# How to update value in row while also using that row in a sub-queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make a room booking system where once somebody requests a booking they are sent a pin number and the booking isn't confirmed until they send that pin number back.

I have made it up to the point where the user can request a booking and it generates a pin number and adds this to the correct table, however I am stuck when trying to update the status of the booking if the pin and username that they enter match a pin number and booking combination.

The user will enter their username and pin number and I want to:

1. update b_status (of the booking where p_bookingId matches b_id) to 'confirmed'
2. delete the row in the pin numbers table that had their pin number in.

In the example of my tables below:

1. Somebody would enter 'jeremy' and '546365'
2. b_status of the row with b_id=2 would be updated to 'confirmed'
3. The row in the pins table would get deleted

I have 3 tables: 'users', 'bookings', and 'pins'.

```
users
------------------
u_id | u_username
------------------
1    | jane
2    | johnny
3    | jeremy
```

.

```
bookings
---------------------------------
b_id | b_userId | b_status
---------------------------------
1    | 2        | pending confirm
2    | 3        | pending confirm
```

.

```
pins
--------------------------------
p_id | p_bookingId | p_pinNumber
--------------------------------
1    | 2           | 546365
```

Comment: Do you know how to write update queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the best practice to delete rows from a table that facilitates transactional operations.

Instead of deleting the PIN, it would be better to add a column to the `pins` table that will store PIN use date, eg `p_pinUsedDate` (and thus mark the PIN as *used*).

Use a variable to look-up the correct booking ID, and then update the `bookings` and `pins` tables:

```
SELECT @b := p_bookingId

FROM bookings b
INNER JOIN pins p
    ON p.p_bookingId = b.b_id
INNER JOIN users u
    ON b.b_userId = u.u_id

WHERE u.u_username = 'jeremy'
AND p.p_pinNumber = '546365'
AND p.p_pinUsedDate IS NULL


IF @b IS NOT NULL THEN

    UPDATE bookings b
    SET b_status = 'confirmed'
    WHERE b_id = @b

    UPDATE pins p
    SET p_pinUsedDate = NOW()
    WHERE p_pinNumber = '546365'
    AND p_bookingId = @b
    AND p.p_pinUsedDate IS NULL

END IF
```